# facebook token expires in 10 days

Tags: facebook-graph-api, token

I've been through many articles and everyone says Facebook token is valide for 60 days. I've tried many times with my app and the token I get is only valid for 10 days. Can someone help?

BTW:I'm using Spring social library for Java.

Updated: Found the problem cause. It's a bug from Spring social. It uses an Integer when calculating dates and it always returned 10 days.

Comment: You have to clarify your question and add some more details. What _kind_ of token are we talking about, how did you check it’s expiry, etc.

Comment: Please consider posting the solution as an answer post.